# Why do multiple setTimeout() calls cause so much lag?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, lag

I have a complex animation sequence involving fades and transitions in JavaScript. During this sequence, which consists of four elements changing at once, a `setTimeout` is used on each element.

Tested in Internet Explorer 9, the animation works at realtime speed (it should take 1.6 seconds and it took exactly 1.6 seconds). ANY other browser will lag horribly, with animation times of 4 seconds (Firefox 3 and 4, Chrome, Opera) and something like 20 seconds in IE 8 and below.

**How can IE9 go so fast while all other browsers are stuck in the mud?**

I have tried to find ways of merging the elements into one, so as to one have one setTimeout at any given time, but unfortunately it wouldn't stand up to any interference (such as clicking a different link to start a new animation before the current one has finished).

EDIT: To elaborate in response to comments, here's the outline of the code:

```
link.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(colourFadeTimeout);
    colourFadeTimeout = setTimeout("colourFade(0);",25);

    clearTimeout(arrowScrollTimeout);
    arrowScrollTimeout = setTimeout("arrowScroll(0);",25);

    clearTimeout(pageFadeOutTimeout);
    pageFadeOutTimeout = setTimeout("pageFadeOut(0);",25);

    clearTimeout(pageFadeInTimeout);
    pageFadeInTimeout = setTimeout("pageFadeIn(0);",25);
}
```

Each of the four functions progress the fade by one frame, then set another timeout with the argument incremented, until the end of the animation.

You can see the page at http://adamhaskell.net/cw/index.html (Username: knockknock; Password: goaway) (it has sound and music, which can be disabled, but be warned!) - my JavaScript is very messy since I haven't really organised it properly, but it is commented a bit so hopefully you can see what the general idea is.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is the animation itself slow, or is there a wait time between different parts of the animation due to waiting for the timeout to occur? Also, some code would help.

Comment: The four parts of the animation are: (1) Fade out current page with `opacity`, (2) Fade in new page with `opacity`, (3) Fade colour of page with `background-color`, (4) Scroll pointer on navigation bar with `left` (Yes this is very overkill, but it's mostly for showing off). The animation should run at 40FPS (timeout interval is 25ms), but in the slower browsers each frame takes at least twice as long and there is visible jumping.

Comment: Posting code could be a pain for you because it's so messy right now...

Comment: Could you maybe post the general structure of the script in pseudocode so we can see where exactly you're employing the `setTimeout`? I'm not very clear on whether whatever animation you're doing is simply slower because it's so elaborate or whether the `setTimeout` calls are delayed.

Comment: Question edited with elaborations and link.

Comment: you're probably missing a dancing baby somewhere

Comment: does performance improves if you take out half the animation or disable the sounds entirely?

Comment: The lag was happening just the same before the sounds were added. Performance improves to realtime if I remove three out of the four parts of the animation, but slows down dramatically with even two of them there.

Comment: To extend on this, a completely different project has a set of up to six trays that can slide out when the user clicks their button. One tray: no problem. Two trays: LAAAAAAAAG (again, in anything but IE9) - I suspect this is something to do with trying to count the timers on one thread or something =/

Comment: I think there's just too f-ing much going on at once, it has little to do with `setTimeout`. You might want to use this page to promote the superior Javascript engine in IE9, but if you're interested in other browsers being able to handle it, you may have to tone down the effects a bit. (Or do them in a better fashion. I'm not really going to look through your messy script for optimizations though. :))

Comment: Okay. Thankfully the examinor said "I'll be using Firefox, but if you tell me in the report that it works better in a particular browser, than I'll go get that and use it instead."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several things:

1. Your timeout is 25ms. This translates to 40fps which is a very high framerate to try to achieve via javascript. Especially for things involving DOM manipulation that may trigger reflows. Increase it to 50 or 60. 15fps should be more than fluid enough for the kinds of animation you're doing. You're not trying to display videos here, just move things around the page.
2. Don't use strings as the first parameter to `setTimeout()`. Especially if you care about performance. That will force javascript to recompile the string each frame of animation. Use a function instead. If you need to pass an argument use an anonymous function to wrap the function you want to execute:

   ```
   setTimeout(function(){
       pageFadeIn(0)
   },50);
   ```

   this will only get compiled once when the script is loaded.
3. As mentioned by Ben, it is cheaper to use a single setTimeout to schedule the functions. For that matter, code clarity may improve by using setInterval instead (or it may not, depends on your coding style).

---

**Additional answer:**

Programming javascript animation is all about optimisation and compromise. It's possible to animate lots of things on the page with little slow-down but you need to know how to do it right and decide what to sacrifice. As an example of just how much can be animated at once is a demo real-time strategy game I wrote a couple of years ago.

Among the things I did to optimize the game are:

1. The walking soldiers are made up of only two frames of animation and I simply toggle between the two images. But the effect is very convincing nonetheless. You don't need perfect animation, just one that looks convincing.
2. I use a single setInterval for everything. It's cheaper CPU-wise and easier to manage. Just decide on a base frame rate and then schedule for different animation to start at different times.

Comment: Again thanks for answer. I wasn't aware you could pass a function to setTimeout - this will make things a lot easier in future! I'll be sure to let you know if it works. I'll also halve the framerate (I made sure to make all the animations have a number of frames that's a power of two, since this allows for easy scaling and maintaings perfect precision in numbers, unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: Okay, got everything working nicely. Firefox is still slower, but I think that's just the engine itself that's better in IE9, 'cos the slowness is nowhere near as bad as it was (it's now taking barely half a second longer than it should). Thank you very much for the help - I didn't know you could pass a function to setTimeout.

Comment: that's a very nice answer (and example)

Comment: @slebetman The link on your answer is no longer avaiable. Could you repost your source, if you still have it?

Comment: I would not call 40fps a very high framerate for JS - it can do very complex stuff at 60fps (I've done this a lot with canvas).  I agree that DOMmanipulations at this rate may be problematic though.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: 40fps was very high framerate in 2010 - it would have slowed IE6 down to a crawl. Yes, in 2010 we still had to support IE6 and IE7

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's a lot of javascript (despite the "quadruple-dose of awesomeness" :)

You're firing a lot of setTimeout sequence, I'm not sure how well JS engines are optimised for this.. particularly IE <= 8

Ok, maybe just a rough suggestion... You could maybe write a small timing engine.

Maintain a global object that stores your current running timed events with the function to run, and the delay...

Then have a single setTimeout handler that check against that global object, and decreases the delay at each iteration and call the function when the delay becomes < 0

you global event would looks something like that:

```
var events = {

        fade1 : {
            fn : func_name,
            delay : 25,
            params : {}
        }

        fadeArrow : {
            fn : func_name,
            delay : 500,
            params : {}
        }

        slideArrow : {
            fn : func_name,
            delay : 500,
            params : {
                arrow:some_value
            }
        }

    }
```

then create a function to loop through these at an interval (maybe 10 or 20 ms) and decrease your delays until they complete and fire the function with params as a paramer to the function (check Function.call for that).

Once down, fire setTimeout again with the same delay..

To cancel an event just unset the property from the events list..

Build a few method to add / remove queued events, update params and so on..

That would reduce everything to just one timeout handler..

(just an idea)

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow (since it's currently 3AM here) and let you know how it turns out.