# Maximum call stack size exceeded error on making Google Map with .csv file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv

I am making an animated google map using .csv file. I have used the code from this link https://github.com/duncancumming/maps/blob/master/animatedPaths/animated%20csv.html

I get a perfect map with the .csv file which is mentioned in this github link. There are over 69000 coordinates in this reference csv file. But with my own .csv file I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. I have over 76000 coordinates in my file. It consists of latitudes and longitudes. My code and .csv file are stored on the client side. This is how my .csv file looks.

```
  30.6011525,-96.3546702
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
  30.6011525,-96.3546703
```

My html file looks like this-:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animated path via a csv file</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var allCoords = [];
    var map, route, marker;

    function getCoords() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'original_toyota.csv',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                var lines = data.split(/[\r\n]+/);

                lines.forEach(function(line){
                    allCoords.push(line.split(','));
                });
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                allCoords.forEach(function(coords){
                    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], 
coords[1]));
                });

                map.fitBounds(bounds);

                drawLine();
            }
        });
    }

    function drawLine() {
        route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            geodesic : true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            editable: false,
            map:map
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < allCoords.length; i++) {
            window.setTimeout(updatePath, 50 * i, allCoords[i]);
        }
    }
    function updatePath(coords) {
        console.log(coords);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
        route.getPath().push(latLng);
        marker.setPosition(latLng);
    }

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: {lat: 51.4788639, lng: -0.0062897},
          zoom: 3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        getCoords();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also shared my code on this link-:https://github.com/sarora7/csvgoogle/tree/master/shivanicsv

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Any help in this will  be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

When I run this code on firefox so I get "too much recursion" error on line map.js:18:374.

Comment: What line does the error point to? What was called prior to getting this message in the stack trace?

Comment: js?v=3.exp:41;             map.js:18 ;              js?v=3.exp:121;     js?v=3.exp:53   ; Ans I am just displaying the array coordinates on console.

Comment: thanks. Now, what line is that in the code you provided? Also, I would be wary of this line `for (var i = 0; i < allCoords.length; i++) { 
 window.setTimeout(updatePath, 50 * i, allCoords[i]); }` You will want to clear those timeouts at some point.

Comment: js?v=3.exp:41; map.js:18 ; js?v=3.exp:121; js?v=3.exp:53 ; I think these points are points to the script for google maps <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

Comment: Can you please explain more about the timeout point, I have not understood.

Comment: are all the points in your csv file valid (have 2 coordinates, latitude < 90)

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of `setTimeout`'s and some users may have performance problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211046/why-do-multiple-settimeout-calls-cause-so-much-lag

Comment: @geocodezip I have checked, all the coordinates are valid.

Comment: When I run this code on firefox so I get "too much recursion" error on line map.js:18:374.

Comment: Does your sample csv file generate the error?

Comment: No, When i tried the code with the .csv file given on this link, the code runs perfectly. That file has over 69000 coordinates. My file has over 76000 coordinates and I get maximum stack exceeded error on chrome and too many recursions on firefox

Comment: I refered this link= https://github.com/duncancumming/maps/blob/master/animatedPaths/animated%20csv.html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (including data that exhibits the issue).